# Connecting to linux mssql server via Entity framework 6.4

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm in the process of migrating `asp.net` app to `asp.net core` app.

Now I have an `asp.net core 3.0` application with `Entity Framework 6.4` and I would like to connect it to `Linux mssql server 2019` running in docker container (image=mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU3-ubuntu-18.04).

When I run the app it throws `PlatformNotSupportedException: LocalDB is not supported on this platform.`

Stacktrace:

```
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, uint waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, bool allowCreate, bool onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, out DbConnectionInternal connection)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, out DbConnectionInternal connection)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, out DbConnectionInternal connection)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher+<>c.<Open>b__13_0(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher<TInterceptor>.Dispatch<TTarget, TInterceptionContext>(TTarget target, Action<TTarget, TInterceptionContext> operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action<TInterceptor, TTarget, TInterceptionContext> executing, Action<TInterceptor, TTarget, TInterceptionContext> executed)
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices+<>c__DisplayClass60_0.<UsingConnection>b__0()
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Execute>b__0()
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute<TResult>(Func<TResult> operation)
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action<DbConnection> act)
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action<DbConnection> act)
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable<int> commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, string createDatabaseScript)
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable<int> commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable<int> commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase()
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection)
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(string targetMigration)
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update()
System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func<DbMigrationsConfiguration, DbContext, MigratorBase> createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<TContext>.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext+<>c__DisplayClass66_0<TContext>.<CreateInitializationAction>b__0()
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext+<>c.<InitializeDatabase>b__58_0(InternalContext c)
System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction<TInput>.PerformAction(TInput input)
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action<InternalContext> action)
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet<TEntity>.Initialize()
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet<TEntity>.get_InternalContext()
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<TResult>.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
System.Linq.Queryable.Single<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
```

SQL server is visible and I'm able to connect to it using `Azure Data Studio`.

I tried specifying the SQL client-provider:

```cs
public class SqlDbConfiguration: DbConfiguration
{
    // providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    public SqlDbConfiguration()
    {
      SetProviderServices(
        SqlProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName,
        SqlProviderServices.Instance);
    }
}
```

Connection string:

```
Data Source=127.0.0.1,1401;Initial Catalog=database; User Id=sa; Password=<YourStrong@Passw0rd\\>;Persist Security Info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
```

Is there something I'm missing? Can I even use `Entity Framework 6.4` in this setup?

Comment: Side note, I really suggest using the `sa` account for an application. Create a `LOGIN` and `USER`s with the minimal permissions the application needs.

Comment: Also, is your SQL Server really running on port `1401`? You don't note in your question that it's running on a non-standard port.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for taking the time. I'm using `sa` account just to quickly test the connection. I'll create a new user after this is resolved. Server is running on port 1401

Comment: Please double-check your connection string.  You should only get that error with a connection string like `"Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;. . . "`

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks. It looks like the connection string from my config file wasn't resolving correctly. All good now.